# Making installer but used SDKs "Classes not registered"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sdk, installation

We are trying to make an installer for our application and are using Advanced Installer.

When i add all the files from the release folder of our application and let it install. The application crashes and says that some classes are not registered. I know this is comming from some of the SDKs we are using that uses ActiveX objects. Do i have to add these SDK installers to the Prerequisites or is there another way to register these classes?

Comment: Getting a program that uses COM objects to compile isn't difficult, the type library is sufficient.  Getting them installed is another matter, you'll have to install them the same way they were installed on your dev machine.  Easy to forget what you did a couple of months ago.  Could be as simple as just running regsvr32, could be as hard as having to use the vendor's installer separately.  Be sure to ask the vendor or owner for proper install procedures.

Comment: The SDKs were just installers and add reference so that wasn't so hard but i don't think it's the meaning that i have to install every SDK on a client PC. Is it possible to make Advanced Installer register all COM objects?

Comment: Of course.  As long as you know how to do it properly.